# React: Cannot call functions from another file

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm new to react and have an Angular background. Everything was working perfectly but then all of a sudden I started getting this error when I was trying to check if firebase is initialized:

```
TypeError: _assets_Services__Firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_11__.default.isInitialised is not a function
```

Here is the concerned snippet of my App.js:

```
import Firebase from './assets/Services/Firebase';

function App() {
  const [isLoggedIn, setLogin] = useState(true)
  const [firebaseInitialized, setFirebaseInitialized] = useState(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    Firebase.isInitialised().then(val => {
      setFirebaseInitialized(val)
    })
  })
```

And here is the Firebase.js:

```
  class Firebase {
      constructor() {
        app.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        this.auth = app.auth();
        this.db = app.firestore();
      }

      isInitialized() {
          return new Promise(resolve => {
              this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(resolve)
          })
      }
```

I did a bit of research and found out some people were having same issues because of version mismatch.
So here is a snippet from my package.json:

```
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create an instance from `Firebase` class then you can access to its methods.

```
const firebase = new Firebase();
firebase.isInitialized()
```

Unless you define `isInitialised` as static.

```
static isInitialized() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    this.auth.onAuthStateChanged(resolve)
  })
}
```

then you can call it like this.

```
Firebase.isInitialized()
```

### Update

Your problem is a typo, your calling it with `isInitialised` which should be `isInitialized`

Comment: Still no luck. After creating the instance it still shows its not a function. TypeError: firebase.isInitialised is not a function.
Even tried defining it as static it still shows the previous error.

Comment: Since it returns a promise you need to use `then`. Are you using it?
`firebase.isInitialised().then(response => console.log(response));`

Comment: Yes! ```Firebase.isInitialised().then(val => {
      setFirebaseInitialized(val)
    })```

Comment: Did you export it? 
`export default Firebase`

Comment: So the problem is a typo, isInitialised => isInitialized

Comment: I did.   ```export default Firebase;```